# asp.net emails getting sent multiple times but works correctly on local machine

Tags: jquery, asp.net

So I am having a strange issue. I have some contact forms on my site that I wrote into an html include file. When the user fills out the form and they click submit I execute some jquery that does an async request to my ashx handler page. Now on my local machine it works as it should all the code gets hit one time and I get 1 email to myself. When I put the code up on our production servers and fill the contact form out I get 3 or 4 copies at different times. The weird thing is that the jquery only gets hit once so I know it isn't calling the ashx page multiple times. Below is my code:

```
function procContact() {
    if ($('#txtFname').val() == '' || $('#txtFname').val() == 'First Name' || $('#txtLname').val() == '' || $('#txtLname').val() == 'Last Name' || $('#txtEmail').val() == '' || $('#txtEmail').val() == 'Email' || $('#txtPhone').val() == '' || $('#txtPhone').val() == 'Phone' || isValidEmailAddress($('#txtEmail').val()) == false) {
        $('#dialog').html('Please fill in all fields before submiting this request.');
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    } else {
        $('#dialog').html('<div style="width: 100%; text-align:center;"><img src="images/loading.gif" /><br />One Moment While We Submit Your Request...</div>');
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        setTimeout(function () {
            sendReq();
        }, 1200);
    }
}

function sendReq() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Myhandler.ashx?function=contact&f=' + $('#txtFname').val() + '&l=' + $('#txtLname').val() + '&e=' + $('#txtEmail').val() + '&p=' + $('#txtPhone').val(),
        cache: false
    }).done(function (html) {
        if (html.indexOf("Success") != -1) {
            //Display thank you
            $('#dialog').html('Thank you for contacting the xxx and we will call you within 2 business days.');

        }

    });
}
```

Now the ASHX stuff

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    If context.Request.QueryString("function") = "contact" Then
        doContact()
    End If

End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

Protected Sub doContact()
    Dim resp As String = ""
    Dim mbody As String = ""
    Dim auth As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx@example.com", "ThePassword")
    Dim mails As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
    Dim mailc As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

    Try
        mailc.Host = "TheSmtpServer"
        mailc.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        mailc.Credentials = auth

        'Email to xxx --------------------------------------------------------------
        mbody = ""

        mails = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("xxx@example.com", "xxx@example.com", "The Subject", mbody)

        mails.IsBodyHtml = True
        mailc.Send(mails)
        mails.Dispose()
        'End xxx Email ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        'Email to Customer --------------------------------------------------------------
        mbody = "the Body stuff"

        mails = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("xxx@example.com", "xxx@example.com", "The Subject", mbody)

        mails.IsBodyHtml = True
        mailc.Send(mails)
        mails.Dispose()
        'End Customer Email ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        resp = "Success"
    Catch ex As Exception
        resp = "Fail"
    End Try
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(resp)
End Sub
```

I am pretty confused at this point as to why it only does this when it is on production.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how does `procContact` get called? please post that code

Comment: procContact gets called via onclick of 
    <input name="button" type="submit" class="btn-green" id="btnSubmit" onclick="procContact();" value="Submit">

Answer (score 0):

Chrome browser (and probably others) on mobile platforms like iOS and android refresh all the open tabs when the browser is simply opened and you visit them.  Any chance you left this page open on your mobile browser, and every time the page refreshes the form is getting re-submitted?

That would explain getting the emails spread throughout the day at different times.

Comment: I use chrome on my desktop but the page isn't set to refresh. I left it open with a javascript break point in the code to see if it gets hit more than once and it never does

Comment: i was asking more if you were testing on a phone or other mobile device, where it auto refreshes the page when you pull it back up

Comment: No i haven't done any mobile testing as the issue is with desktop for now.

Comment: So when I put in a session variable that is set when the messages sends it still sends multiple times. This would indicate a problem outside the code wouldn't it?

Comment: thats hard to say.  If you had a variable that was updated with the date/time of the send every time the send code was called, and that session variable was the same after the first email you got as the second email minutes or  hours later, then yes, probably points to an issue outside.

Comment: I changed the SMTP server to use gmail and everything seems to be working as expected. No multiple emails. Looks like I'll have to get in touch with our network admin and find out what he may have changed recently as this has never happened before with any other sites and forms I have done using the same smtp server as i am trying to use now.